# ReactJs Application Cache Client not see latest changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, caching, browser-cache

So I have a Application in production and some of my clients are complaining that they can't see the new changes unless they completely wipe their cache.

Techs: React

What i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in the head tag for [Learn More](https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/03/how-to-clear-browser-cache-in-react/#:%7E:text=To%20clear%20browser%20cache%20in%20React%2C%20we%20can%20add%20meta,the%20page%20isn%27t%20cached.&text=in%20the%20head%20tag%20to,make%20sure%20nothing%20is%20cached.)

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: Thank you man. I have to ask something, is there any negative side to use this ?